# Swift: Make custom ErrorType enum accept NSError?

Tags: swift, error-handling, nserror

When working with ErrorType I can write a function that takes in an ErrorType argument like so:

```
func myFunc(e:ErrorType) {

}
```

I can then call it even if I pass in an NSError:

```
let nserror = NSError(domain: "test.domain", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
myFunc(nserror)
```

This all works.

What I want to figure out is if there is a way to have my own error enum accept an nserror jus like ErrorType does. So for example:

```
enum Error:Int, ErrorType {
    case Error1
    case Error2
    case Error3
    case Error4
}

func myFunc(e:Error) {

}
```

this will not work:

```
myFunc(nserror)
```

Is there a way to make myFunc accept NSError objects even if the argument is Error?

Comment: There's no way of doing that, because it doesn't make any sense: Error is a subtype of ErrorType and NSError is a subtype of ErrorType, but that doesn't make NSError a subtype of Error. **An NSError is not your Error type**. What would you even use this for? I think you actually want something different than that.

Comment: I wanted to be able to get into the function errors coming from Objective-C code. ErrorType allows that. I was wondering if there was some kind of workaround to do that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What's wrong with `ErrorType`?

Comment: Good question. I guess nothing is wrong with ErrorType. I am using the Error type around my app for app specific error handling, I naturally went to accept "Error" instead of ErrorType. I am not sure at the moment what the better approach is.

Comment: Ok, so, if I use ErrorType then I cannot use the comparing function to compare two "Error" enum value since I have Error:Int... , that does not work on ErrorType.